# User not able to login to grafana once logged out

Tags: ldap, grafana

I am using Grafana version: 2.6.0. I have integrated LDAP authentication. I log into grafana using LDAP auth but once I log out I am unable to log back in. Error:-

```
2018/03/01 13:13:41 [login.go:102 LoginPost()] [E] Error while trying to authenticate user: UNIQUE constraint failed: user.email
2018/03/01 13:13:41 [I] Completed 10.200.4.190 - "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 53 bytes in 8941us
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to pass strings for email and username in follwoing section of ldap.toml

```
[servers.attributes]
name = "givenName"
surname = "sn"
username = "cn"
member_of = "memberOf"
email =  "email"
```

This is similar as to providing search_filter.